# Rewriting $\frac{\operatorname d}{\operatorname dx}\min(x,n+1)$ using only the basic arithmetic.

Tags: functions, summation, arithmetic, sums-of-squares

So I wonder if it is possible to find an equal expression to an expression: $\frac{d}{dx}min(x,n+1)$ which is defined only by the basic operations? <s>All the variables are integers, so it shouldn't matter that as a function, it is discontinuous.</s>  (edit: *I was corrected by @fleablood, that you can't differentiate of integers. What I meant was that after the differentiation, I'm only interested in the integers, because I'm using them as the lower and upper limit. But I realised that it is irrelevant regarding the problem.*)

I was trying to find a formula for the sum of squares with an arbitrary lower limit: $\sum_{k=x}^n k^2$, but could only find $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2= \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$, which works only if the lower limit is equal to 1 (or 0).

I've discovered, that you can express the first more *general* sum as:

$$\sum_{k=x}^n k^2 = \biggr(\frac{d}{dx}min(x,n+1)\biggr)\biggr(\sum_{k=1}^{-x} k^2+\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 - \sum_{k=1}^{x-1}k^2\biggr)$$

That means that I can express the more *general* sum of squares using the sums of squares with lower limit equal to 1. Therefore I can rewrite the expression as:

$$\sum_{k=x}^n k^2 = \biggr(\frac{d}{dx}min(x,n+1)\biggr)\biggr(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-\frac{x(x-1)(2x-1)}{6}\biggr)$$

I am happy with the expression in the right parentheses, but it only works with the alien-looking expression in the left parentheses, so I am trying to find an equal expression that uses only the basic operations.

Since English is not my first language, I might have used some terms incorrectly or awkwardly. But I hope, that the question makes sense. Also I'm really not that good at math, so it is highly probable that I've made an error, or I'm doing it unnecessarily complicated.

(edit 2: *So I've found out that you can rewrite the expression in question as:*

$$\frac{d}{dx}min(x,n+1)=\frac{1}{2}\biggr(1-\frac{x-n-1}{|x-n-1|}\biggr)$$

*- therefore the more* general *sum of squares can be rewriten as:*

$$\sum_{k=x}^n k^2 =\frac{1}{2}\biggr(1-\frac{x-n-1}{|x-n-1|}\biggr)\biggr(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}-\frac{x(x-1)(2x-1)}{6}\biggr)=\frac{(|x-n-1|-x+n+1)(n(n+1)(2n+1)-x(x-1)(2x-1))}{12|x-n-1|}$$

***- So my new question: Is this the optimal formula? Meaning, is it the most practical one? When you need to sum squares starting with arbitrary lower limit, is this the formula, you would probably use?*** - end of edit 2)

Comment: The $\min$ function is not differentiable.

Comment: Can you explain what is *x*? Is it an integer or a general real number? If *x* is real, what does the summation notation mean?

Comment: @copper.hat Oh. Does that mean, that the *max* function is also not differentiable? I used the changed Heaviside step function and at wikipedia, it is defined as the derivative of the max function [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) . Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Mann Yes, the x is an integer. I was plotting it at Desmos, so it is the remnant of that.

Comment: You don't differentiate of integers.  $\lim_{h\to 0; x+h \in \mathbb Z} \frac {f(x+h) -f(x)}h$ makes no sense and is meaningless. But of $x\in \mathbb R$ (or even in $\mathbb Q$ or a set there are elements between any two) and if $x$ is a variable and $n$ is costant then $$\min(x,n+1)=\begin{cases}x&x\le n+1\\n+1&x> n+1\end{cases}$$ and $$\frac d{dx}\min(x,n+1)=\begin{cases}x&1< n+1\\undefined&x= n+1\\0&x> n+1\end{cases}$$

Comment: @fleablood Thank you for your answer! Oh, you are right. I'm still somewhat inept regarding calculus. Right, so I assume that it is okay to use the derivative this way.

Comment: $f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac {f(x+h) -f(x)}h$ ***IF*** the limit exists.  If $x < n+1; h<n+1 - x$ then $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {f(x+h) -f(x)}h = \lim \frac {\min(x+h, n+1) -\min(x,n+1)}h=\lim \frac {(x+h)-x}h = \lim \frac hh=\lim 1 = 1$.  And if $x > n+1$ and $h < x-(n+1)$ then $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {f(x+h) -f(x)}h = \lim \frac {\min(x+h, n+1) -\min(x,n+1)}h=\lim \frac {(n+1)-(n+1)}h = \lim \frac 0h=\lim = 0$.  But if $x=n+1$ we have $\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h=\lim\frac{(n+1+h)-(n+1+h)}h=0$ but $\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h=\lim\frac{(x+h)-x}h=1$ so there is no limit at $x = n+1$.

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_Mathematics. There is a lot of info about summation

Answer (score 2):

Let's denote $\Delta f(x) = f(x+1) - f(x)$, and  $ x^{\downarrow m} = \underbrace{x \cdot (x - 1) \cdot \dots \cdot (x - m + 1)}_{m \ times}, $ then

$\Delta (x^{\downarrow m}) = (x+1)^{\downarrow m} - x^{\downarrow m} = (x+1) \cdot x \cdot (x - 1) \cdot \dots \cdot (x - m + 2)  - x \cdot (x - 1) \cdot \dots \cdot (x - m + 2) \cdot (x - m + 1)  = \underbrace{x \cdot (x - 1) \cdot \dots \cdot (x - m + 2)}_{x^{\downarrow (m-1)}}  \cdot \left (  x + 1 - x + m - 1 \right) = m \cdot x^{\downarrow (m-1)}$

$\sum\limits_{x=a}^b \Delta f(x) = \Delta f(a) + \Delta f(a+1) + \dots + \Delta f(b) = f(a + 1) - f(a) + f(a + 2) - f(a + 1) + \dots + f(b+1) - f(b) = f(b + 1) - f(a)$

So: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^{\downarrow r} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{\Delta k^{\downarrow (r+1)}}{r+1} = \frac{1}{r+1} \cdot \left(   (n+1)^{\downarrow (r+1)} - \underbrace{1^{\downarrow (r+1)}}_{0}    \right) = \frac{(n+1) \cdot n \cdot (n - 1) \cdot (n - 2) \cdot \dots \cdot (n - r + 1)}{r+1}$

Comment: This is very interesting! I see now, how you can find a formula for sum of k raised to any power with an arbitrary lower limit incorporated into it. The one problem I have with this however is that it doesn't work, when lower limit is greater than upper limit (that from my understanding should always yield an empty sum: zero). This is why I've added the derivative of the *min* function to the expression. When lower limit is greater than upper limit ($x>n+1$), the derivative should yield a zero, thus making the whole expression equal to zero. Is there another (better) way, to accomplish this?